# Filling smart_pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class for reading triangular meshs (.obj) files. Members are:

```
template< class T >
class TrigMeshFile
{
public:
    bool init_;
    U32 vertexCount_;
    U32 trigCount_;
    std::shared_ptr< T > vertexData_;
    std::shared_ptr< U32 > trigVertexIndex_;
}
public:
    init_(false);
    vertexCount_(0);
    trigCount_(0);
    vertexData_(nullptr);
    trigVertex_index(nullptr);
};
```

Lets say my data is

```
v -3.000000 1.800000 0.000000
v -2.991600 1.800000 -0.081000
v -2.991600 1.800000 0.081000
```

When I manually try to enter the data, I am getting errors.

```
TrigMeshFile<float> trigMeshFile;
trigMeshFile.init_ = true;
trigMeshFile.vertexCount_ = 9;
trigMeshFile.trigCount_ = 3;
trigMeshFile.vertexData_[0] = -3.000000;
```

So the question is how to fill shared_ptr?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr`s are not "filled", they point to a location in memory.  Perhaps you want to use some kind of container?  It seems that you want `vertexData_` to represent an arbitrary number of `float` triplets.

Comment: Why is there a runaway `}` in the middle of your class? Furthermore is it really necessary to use shared pointers to data probably takes half as much memory as even a raw pointer let alone a shared pointer? Btw: for non-array template parameters the `[]` may not even be defined, so `trigMeshFile.vertexData_ = std::make_unique<float>(-3.000);` would be the appropriate way dynamically allocating a new `float` that is initialized with 1, or alternatively `*trigMeshFile.vertexData_ = -3.000;` if the smart pointer is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not need `std::shared_ptr<T>` but an internal array of vertices like

```cpp
template< class T >
class TrigMeshFile
{
private:
    std::vector< T > vertexData_;
    std::vector< U32 > trigVertexIndex_;
public:
    void addVertex( const T& vertex, U32 index ) {
        vertexData_.push_back( vertex );
        trigVertexIndex_.push_back( index );
    }
};
```

You do not need the fields `init_` or `vertexCount_` as you can replace them with `vertexData_.empty()` and `vertexData_.size()`

```cpp
    bool initialized() const {
        return !vertexData_.empty();
    }
    size_t count() const {
        return vertexData_.size();
    }
```

Or better yet, you can put these two fields together

```cpp
class TrigMeshFile
{
private:
    struct Point {
        T vertex;
        U32 index;
    };
    std::vector< Point > vertices_;
public:
    void addVertex( const T& vertex, U32 index ) {
        vertices_.push_back( Point{vertex,index} );
    }
};
```

However I realize that if you are using the above structure with OpenGL you might want to keep both arrays separated for performance reasons.

Comment: Minor point: obj files do not have a 1:1 mapping between vertices and vertex indices. You probably want the addVertex method to ONLY take 1 vertex (since the 'v' lines are read independently). You'd probably then want a method such as addTriangle(int i0, int i1, int i2) to add an entire 'f' line. (I'm assuming the OP has triangulated the data)

Comment: @robthebloke True. I hope the OP realizes that.